# How to filter a list by all parameters on another list

Tags: c#, .net, list, filter

I'm working on a C# WPF application and I'm facing an issue where I have to filter a list based on all the elements existing in another list.

I have a list of products which contains products structure as follows.

**Note:** I have kept the data types as string only for the simplicity here. Please ignore the data types.

```
Struct Products {
  string id;
  string name;
  string category;
  string price;
  string rating;
}
```

And the list

```
List<Product> m_list;
```

I have a number of list objects that contain different elements for the filter operation.

```
List<strings> filters = new List<strings>("name")
List<strings> filters = new List<strings>("name", "price")
List<strings> filters = new List<strings>("name", "price", "category")
```

I want something like

```
result = m_list.findAll(item => filters.Contains(item.name =="name" && item.category == "category" && item.price= "price"));
```

Of course I can do this but for that I should have a fixed amount of items in the filters list.

I want to add dynamic behavior in this filter operation so it can handle any number of parameters in the filters list and returns the resulting value.

Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: I don't think you've clearly thought out your problem statement. `new List<strings>("name", "price", "category")` is clearly not the data you're searching for - and some of your lists don't have all of the elements. Can you tell me what the list would look like if you are searching for a category called "apple"?

Comment: Have you considered the `Intersect()` method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function inside `Products` struct to compare all the given properties from the list,

```
public struct  Products 
{
  string Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
  string Category { get; set; }
  string Price { get; set; }
  string Rating { get; set; }

  public bool IsValid(List<string> filter) => filters.Contains(this.Name) 
                && filters.Contains(this.Category) 
                && filters.Contains(this.Price);
}
```

Now use `IsValid()` function to filter the `m_list`,

```
result = m_list.Where(x => x.IsValid(filters));
```

Comment: Wouldn't it return false if I pass just name and price is in this case?
It still isn't giving us the dynamic behavior. It will be true only when filters list has all three elements available.

Comment: Have you tried `||` instead of `&&`. This change will check first `true` condition and will return result